# ¿Cómo hacer múltiples gráficos con ggplot2 usando for?

Tags: r, bucle-for, ggplot2

Me surgió la curiosidad de como realizar múltiples gráficos en `ggplot2` usando el loop `for`.

Por ejemplo si tengo este marco de datos.

```
df1<-read.csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/AER/Journals.csv")
```

Y deseo hacer un gráfico de dispersión entre la variable `price` con: `pages`, `charpp`, `citations` y `subs`.

Para lo cual lo podría generar cada gráfico por separado. Y los junto todos con la función `plot_grid()` del paquete `cowplot`

```
library(ggplot2)

f1<-ggplot(df1, aes(x=pages, y=price))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()

f2<-ggplot(df1, aes(x=citations, y=price))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()

f3<-ggplot(df1, aes(x=subs, y=price))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()

f4<-ggplot(df1, aes(x=charpp, y=price))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()

library(cowplot)
plot_grid(f1,f2,f3,f4)
```

A lo que obtengo el siguiente resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al tratar de hacer el mismo procedimiento ¿con un `for` cómo se haría? dejaré una respuesta, la única que sé. Pero **sería genial si pueden compartir otras formas más eficientes de hacerlas**.

Answer (score 1):

La única forma que sé es usando `aes_string` en vez de `aes`.

Primero defino un vector con el nombre de las variables que van a variar.

```
nombres<-c("pages","charpp","citations","subs")
```

Luego realizo el `for` de la siguiente manera:

```
# Voy a cambiar el color y tamaño de los puntos del gráfico para hacer una diferenciación.
for (i in 1:4) {
  assign(paste0("g_",i),ggplot(df1, aes_string(x=nombres[i], y="price"))+
           geom_point(col="blue", size=2)+
           ylab("Precio")+
           theme_bw())
}

# Para posteriormente unirlos. 

plot_grid(g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4)
```

Y el resultado esperado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para guardar los plots estoy usando la función `assign()` pero podría haberlo hecho creando una lista vacía antes del `for()` en donde podría haber guardado los objetos. Pero sería un poco más complicado colocarlo estos objetos en la función `plot_grid()`. La forma alternativa la muestro a continuación:

```
plots<-list()
for (i in 1:4) {
  p<-ggplot(df1, aes_string(x=nombres[i], y="price"))+
           geom_point(col="red", size=2)+
           ylab("Precio")+
           theme_bw()
  plots[[i]]<-p
}

plot_grid(plots[[1]],plots[[2]],plots[[3]],plots[[4]])
```

Espero les sirva. Como les mencioné sería genial si comparten otras formas de poder hacer gráficos con `ggplot2` usando el loop `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma bien sencilla, y natural a `ggplot` es aprovechar el "facetado" por variable, para eso simplemente hay que "acomodar" los datos usando algo de `dplyr\tidyverse`:

```
df1 %>% 
  select(price, pages, citations, subs, charpp) %>% 
  pivot_longer(!price) %>% 
  head()


# A tibble: 6 x 3
  price name      value
  <int> <chr>     <int>
1   123 pages       440
2   123 citations    21
3   123 subs         14
4   123 charpp     3822
5    20 pages       309
6    20 citations    22
```

Con `pivot_longer()` transformamos la estructura horizontal en una vertical, dónde cada valor de las 4 variables se transforma en una fila y una nueva variable `name` que indica a que variable original corresponde el valor. Finalmente, usamos `facet_wrap()` para fraccionar el gráfico por cada variable:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1<-read.csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/AER/Journals.csv")
df1 %>% 
  select(price, pages, citations, subs, charpp) %>% 
  pivot_longer(!price) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("pages", "citations", "subs", "charpp"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=value, y=price)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales="free") +
  theme_bw(
```

)

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, siempre es un gusto leerlo.